# Rails app deployment on Heroku getting error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I deployed my rails app on heroku with mysql as db.It is saying like We're sorry, but something went wrong.
Here I am adding my heroku logs plz some one help me.

```
2017-03-22T10:43:48.752701+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-03-22T10:43:48.752807+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-22 10:43:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2017-03-22T10:43:48.790015+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2017-03-22T10:43:48.752761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-22 10:43:48] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2017-03-22T10:43:48.790019+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:14662
2017-03-22T10:43:48.790024+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-22T10:43:48.790020+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-22T10:43:48.790020+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2017-03-22T10:43:48.890675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2017-03-22T10:43:51.674432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 52776 -e production`
2017-03-22T10:43:56.654276+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-22 10:43:56] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2017-03-22T10:43:56.657326+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-22 10:43:56] INFO  ruby 2.2.6 (2016-11-15) [x86_64-linux]
2017-03-22T10:43:56.657804+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-03-22 10:43:56] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4 port=52776
2017-03-22T10:43:56.776993+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-22T10:44:10.744223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tranquil-ridge-41580.herokuapp.com request_id=e39fe9d2-3d4d-4d70-a130-cb81b3b17d47 fwd="183.82.43.238" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1754 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 1):

Heroku natively uses postgres. Life will be easier for you if you use that locally.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku supports postgres dbs and not mysql

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#database

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile include

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
  gem "rails_12factor"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On heroku, only pg database is available, so add following code in gmfile

## Gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

then run

```
bundle install
```